# how to finish this latex drawing with an angle between two arcs and two pictures and arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following TikZ picture that I managed to draw:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);

\foreach \x in {30,45} {
                % lines from center to point
                \draw[black,->] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:1cm);
                % dots at each point
                \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
        }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to add the following elements to it:

1. I want to add an angle marker (part of a circle with "x" in it) between the two arrows.
2. I want to have an image to the left of the circle and an image to the right of the circle, and two lines, one coming from the left image to the left arrow in the circle and one coming from the right arrow in the circle to the right image (not sure if it completely makes sense, but the idea is to map each image to one of the vectors).

Comment: The circle is kinda small for the angle marker to be visible, though. :P

Comment: it can be enlarged... @Alenanno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on pure guessing ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   angle radius = 7mm,
my angle/.style = {draw,
                   angle eccentricity=1.2,
                   font=\footnotesize,
                   <->}, % angle label position!
    Arrow/.style= {ultra thick,gray,-stealth, 
                   shorten <=7mm, %shorten >=0.5mm,
                   draw=gray}
                    ]
\coordinate  (c) at (0,0);
\draw[thick] (c) circle(1cm);
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {30,45} 
{
% dots at each point
    \filldraw[gray] (\x:1cm) circle(1pt);
% lines from center to point
    \draw[black,->] (c) -- coordinate (m\i) (\x:1cm) coordinate (a\i);
}
\pic [my angle,"$x$"]  {angle = a1--c--a2};
\pic [my angle,"$x$",red,angle radius = 10mm,]  {angle = a1--c--a2};
% left image, simulated by node
\node (li)  [draw, minimum size=20mm,align=center,left]  at (-2,0) {left\\ image};
\node (ri)  [draw, minimum size=20mm,align=center,right] at ( 2,0) {right\\ image};
    \draw[Arrow]    (li.center) to [out=45, in=135]  (m2);
    \draw[Arrow]    (ri.center) to [out=225,in=-60]  (m1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If my guessing is correct, I wil ad short explanation (if this would be necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is a solution to your question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);

        \foreach \x in {15,60} {
            % lines from center to point
            \draw[black,->] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:1cm);
            % dots at each point
            \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
        }

        \draw[->] (15:0.5cm) arc (15:60:0.5);
        \node at(35:0.3cm) {$x$};

        % left image
        \draw[thick] (-2.5cm,0cm) circle (1cm);

        % right image
        \draw[thick] (2.5cm,0cm) circle(1cm);

        % line from left image to the left arrow
        \draw[->] (-2.5cm,0cm) -- (60:1cm);

        % line from the right arrow to the right image
        \draw[->] (15:1cm) -- (2.5cm,0cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```